Separate one column into multiple in R
Starting in row 2, column 2, I need the numerical values separated out into the remaining columns (2:7)
This is the data
structure(list(State = c("State", "Alabama ", "Alaska ", "Arizona ", 
"Arkansas ", "California "), `Number of farms 2022` = c("number", 
"37,400    37,100    8,600     8,600      230       232", "1,200     1,200      870       870      725       725", 
"16,700    16,400   25,500    25,000    1,527     1,524", "37,800    37,400   13,700    13,700      362       366", 
"63,100    62,900   24,200    23,800      384       378"), `Number of farms 2023` = c("number", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Land in farms 2022` = c("1,000 acres", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Land in farms 2023` = c("1,000 acres", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Average farm size 2022` = c("acres", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `Average farm size 2023` = c("acres", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

I want it to look something like this:
State | Number of farms 2022 | Number of farms 2023 | Land in farms 2022 | Land in farms 2023 | Average farm size 2022 | Average farm size 2023
State | number | number | 1,000 acres | 1,000 acres | acres | acres
Alabama | 37,400  |  37,100  |  8,600   |  8,600   |   230   |    232

Since I have multiple files for different years, I would need this code to be easily applicable to all of them.
I have seen codes like this
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(player, c('First', 'Last'))

but I'm not sure how to make it applicable to my data frame since the columns are already named.
Not sure if this helps, but the original data comes from the USDA website dated Feb 16, 2024: https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/5712m6524
Then I load it in like this
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

df = read.delim('file.txt', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

df=df[106:167,]
df=data.frame(df)

df = cSplit(df, "df",":")

And do a ton of processing from there. I need the text file because I'm creating a time-series and USDA's ZIP files only go back to 2002.

This will be easier to fix upstream, if that's an option for you. How are you loading the data?

The original text file is from the USDA website dated Feb 16, 2024: https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/5712m6524. I read it in like this: ```df = read.delim('file.txt', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
df=df[106:167,]
df=data.frame(df)
library(splitstackshape)
f = cSplit(df, "df",":") ``` and process from there.

Since this is about data cleaning/preparing read_fwf might be the right tool for the job
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

read_fwf(file = "fnlo0224.txt", 
         col_positions = fwf_positions(c(1,  21, 30, 40, 49, 59, 68), 
                                       c(20, 29, 39, 48, 58, 67, 77)),
         skip_empty_rows = TRUE)[109:164,] %>% 
  rename_with(~ c("state", "nfarms2022", "nfarms2023", 
                  "landinfarms2022", "landinfarms2023", "avgfarmsize2022", 
                  "avgfarmsize2023")) %>% 
  mutate(state = trimws(sub("\\..*:", "", state)), 
         across(-state, ~ as.numeric(gsub(",", "", .x)))) %>% 
  filter(state != ":")

# A tibble: 50 × 7
   state   nfarms2022 nfarms2023 landinfarms2022 landinfarms2023 avgfarmsize2022
   <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Alabama      37400      37100            8600            8600             230
 2 Alaska        1200       1200             870             870             725
 3 Arizona      16700      16400           25500           25000            1527
 4 Arkans…      37800      37400           13700           13700             362
 5 Califo…      63100      62900           24200           23800             384
 6 Colora…      36100      35900           30200           30000             837
 7 Connec…       5100       5100             370             370              73
 8 Delawa…       2150       2150             520             520             242
 9 Florida      44700      44400            9700            9700             217
10 Georgia      39200      39000           10000           10000             255
# ℹ 40 more rows
# ℹ 1 more variable: avgfarmsize2023 <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

If you have multiple files you can simply cat them together in a shell, import with read_fwf and filter by row number.

This is FANTASTIC!! I noticed the US values are not in here, so I changed 163 to 164. Doing so causes the first two US values from the first two columns to disappear. Any idea how to fix that?

Good question. Gonna take a look...

Uh, it's because of the two , in the million values, gonna change the sub to a gsub to account for that! Sorry :)

For any future visitors who may have the same issue:
I could not have figured this out without the expertise of Andre Wildberg, but  I had to make a few modifications for a couple of reasons:

Adding in the row containing the United States deletes the first two elements in the last row
This code will need to be used on multiple text files that contain data for different years, so I needed to extract the year from the text file. (I hope to use this in a loop later)

Using my original example with a slightly modified version of Andre's code, we get:
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(splitstackshape)

# Read in whole text file
data = read_fwf(file = "fnlo0224.txt")

# Get Years
years = data[105,]
years = cSplit(years, "X1",":", type.convert = F)

# Create column names
dfNames = c("State", "Number of farms", "Number of farms", "Land in farms", "Land in farms", "Average farm size", "Average farm size")

# Append the year to the end of the column name
dfNames <- paste(dfNames, years, sep = " ")
dfNames = trimws(dfNames, which = "right")


# Step 1: Read the relevant data
f <- read_fwf(
  file = "fnlo0224.txt",
  col_positions = fwf_positions(c(1, 21, 30, 40, 49, 59, 68), c(20, 29, 39, 48, 58, 67, 77)),
  skip_empty_rows = TRUE
)

# Step 2: Subset the required rows
f <- f[109:164, ]

# Step 3: Rename the columns and clean
f <- f %>%
  rename_with(~ dfNames) %>%  # Rename columns using dfNames
  mutate(
    State = trimws(sub("\\..*:", "", State)),  # Clean 'State' column
    across(-State, ~ as.numeric(gsub(",", "", .x)))  # Clean and convert other columns to numeric
  ) %>%
  filter(State != ":")

